# Requests check if user is authenticated or not

Tags: laravel

I was asked to check if the user is logged in or not
I have been given a sample code

```
 public function getAllNfts(GetAllNfts $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $data = $request->getData();
        $data['uuid'] = ($request->hasHeader('Authorization') && $request->header('Authorization')) ? $this->token_service->getUserUUIDFromToken($request) : null;
        $requested_uuid = $request->getRequestedUUID();
        return $this->nft_service->getAllNfts(uuid: $requested_uuid, data: $data);
    }
```

But I do not have uuid for my code when I work on the admin and json is not used because it is in the admin panel
This is my code

```
public function updateCollection(EditCollection $request):RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->validated();
        $data = $request->all();
        $this->collection_repository->updateCollection($data);
        return redirect('collections');
    }
```

THis is FOrm Request Validate `EditCollection.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EditCollection extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => ['required', 'string','max:255', 'min:10', 'between:10,255'],
            'status' => ['required','Boolean','size:1'],
        ];
    }
}
```

How to check all requests to see if the user is authenticated
And not contrary to the sample code

Comment: What type of classes are `GetAllNfts ` && `EditCollection `?

Comment: These are created in the controller

Comment: Pleas help me:(((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: Are those FormRequest classes? Those are not Laravel default so i'm not sure what those are.

Comment: I edited my questions, please look again

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to check for each request as long as you're using Laravel's Middleware. Take a look at this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#defining-middleware).

Comment: I think so too, but the **leader** wants me to do the same.

Comment: If that's the case then you also to post the code for `GetAllNfts` class. That way we can see what he wanted you to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this  `$data->user_id = Auth::id();` and then import this statement, `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case you can use form request class to check before process that request

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EditCollection extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return auth()->check();
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => ['required', 'string','max:255', 'min:10', 'between:10,255'],
            'status' => ['required','Boolean','size:1'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Add this lines to the all request that you need to validate if the user is logged

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return auth()->check();
    }
```

I hope its helps you